# dissoc a key in a vector of hashmaps in a cond->

Tags: vector, clojure, hashmap

How do I remove **:z** of **data** inside a cond-> ?

```
(def data
  {:a [{:x 1
        :y 2
        :z "remove this"}
       {:x 3
        :y 4
        :z 5}]
   :b "b"
   :c "c"})
```

I suspect I'll have to used update-in, but I have not been having success.

```
(cond-> data
        :a (#(<function to remove :z when :z is "remove this">))
        :b (dissoc :b))
```

My current theory is to use update-in, map, and an if statement. I have not been able to find the exact syntax that works, though

```
(cond-> data
        :a (#(update-in (:a %) [:z]
                        (map (fn [A]
                               (if (= (:z A) "remove this")
                                 (dissoc A :z)
                                 A))
                             (:a %))))
        :b (dissoc :b))
=> ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  clojure.core/apply (core.clj:652)
```

Comment: Could you please add the code you have tried and how it failed so we can improve on it?

Comment: Updated. I have been trying different variations of what I added to the bottom of the question, but I am not sure if I am doing the anonymous functions correct or even if there is a better strategy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt there is very close:

You seem to do navigate twice "into" the map. If you want to change the items of `:a` in that map, then `update` is enough.  Also you don't have to path via `:z`, since this is the one you want to `dissoc` from the map.

So my suggestion here is:

```
(cond-> data
  :a (update :a
             (partial mapv #(if (= (:z %) "remove this") (dissoc % :z) %)))
  :b (dissoc :b))
```

- `update` because we change only the top level
- remember, the first param to `update` comes from `cond->`
- `mapv` to keep the vector
- the first param to the function passed to `update` will be `(:a data)`, but `mapv` takes this as last argument - so use `partial` here
- this leaves us with the option to use the function literal as mapping function (remember, no nesting of function literals); of course this function is a candidate to extract into its own function

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!
I had never used partial, before. This is super interesting and a I appreciate the very comprehensive answer

Answer (score 1):

maybe you would also want to take a look at [specter](https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter):

```
(require '[com.rpl.specter :refer [ALL NONE setval]])

(cond->> data
  :a (setval [:a ALL :z #{"remove this"}] NONE)
  :b (setval :b NONE))

;;=> {:a [{:x 1, :y 2} {:x 3, :y 4, :z 5}], :c "c"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would break down a problem a bit, so you process the data in stages. Using my [favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template), we get the following:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [data   {:a [{:x 1
                     :y 2
                     :z "remove this"}
                    {:x 3
                     :y 4
                     :z 5}]
                :b "b"
                :c "c"}
        result (update data :a
                 (fn [vec-of-maps]
                   (mapv #(dissoc % :z) vec-of-maps)))]
    (is= result
      {:a [{:x 1 :y 2}
           {:x 3 :y 4}]
       :b "b"
       :c "c"})))
```

You can `dissoc` the `:b` separately if you desire.